# DOMCrawler find Tag with Inner HTML text

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

I'm trying to use Goutte to scrape a web page and I can't find a `DOMCrawler` method to search for actual text. Let's say there's a `td`, but it has no class or ID. So, I need to search for let's say "Title" then get that `td`s next sibling.

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to refer you to the DomCrawlers documentation on [Node Filtering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-filtering), specifically the [DomCrawler::reduce()](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_reduce) method and [Accessing Node Values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values)

If you aren't happy with accessing these then you can always drop down and use [DOMNode properties](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Of course you might have better luck with using XPath queries which are extremely powerful.